# Split large ArrayList into chunks and iterate asynchronously

Tags: java, android, performance

Is there any efficient way to iterate large `ArrayList` (100k size)

```
for(Set set : sets) {
   //complex logic
}
```

Is there a way to split the `ArrayList` into multiple smaller `ArrayList` and iterate them into their own thread?

Edit:
It's in Android and I can't use streams in API 16

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#parallelStream--

Comment: @JBNizet Sorry, forgot to mention, I'm in Android. Streams is for api24 and above. My minimum version is api16, so is there any similar way like the Stream?

Comment: You can create an ExecutorService (see Executors), with a fixed number of threads N (typically, the number of cores your phone has), and split the list in N parts and submit N tasks to the ExecutorService (using invokeAll). But doing things in parallel doesn't necessarily make things faster. If there is a single core, it will inevitably make it slower, and if the business logic has high contention over a shared resource, the gain can be negligible, or even negative.

Comment: You can rxJava for this. https://praveer09.github.io/technology/2016/02/29/rxjava-part-3-multithreading/

Comment: If you goal is to apply math operations on array items then OpenGL ES shaders is your option. They do math on arrays very fast because operations are called on GPU. Also take a look at [Android Render Script](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/compute.html)

Comment: In addition to previous comment: excerpt "RenderScript is primarily oriented for use with data-parallel computation. The RenderScript runtime parallelizes work across processors available on a device, such as multi-core CPUs and GPUs"

Answer (score 0):

Programatically it should be possible in Android to split the large list into multiple sub list and assign the thread to asynchronously do the task. Here is what the code in Java looks like and I assume Android will be something similar:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class SplitArrayList {

public SplitArrayList() {
}

public void split(List<Integer> list) {
    int start = 0;
    while (start < list.size() - 1) {
        assignTask(list.subList(start, start + 10000));
        start += 10000;
    }
}

public void assignTask(List<Integer> subList) {
    new TaskThread(subList).start();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SplitArrayList obj = new SplitArrayList();
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        list.add(new Integer(i));
    }
    obj.split(list);
    }
}

class TaskThread extends Thread {

private List<Integer> subList;

public TaskThread(List<Integer> subList) {
    this.subList = subList;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    System.out.println("Starting from " + this.subList.get(0) + " and ending on "
            + this.subList.get(this.subList.size() - 1) + " with size " + this.subList.size());
}
}
```